# Rendering with recursion for a nested list in React - how to avoid unnecessary updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, redux, immutability

I have a `list` object in my redux state. It has a byId set of like this:

```
{
    root: {
        id: 'root',
        children: ['item_1', 'item_2'],
        data: 'Root String',
        parent: null,
    },
    item_1: {
        id: 'item_1',
        children: ['item_1_1', 'item_1_2', 'item_1_3'],
        data: 'Some String',
        parent: 'root',
    },
    item_1_1:
    {
        id: 'item_1_1'
        children: ['item_1_1_1', 'item_1_1_2']
        data: 'Some Other string',
        parent: 'item_1',
    },
    item_2: {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I'm rendering the above list like the following:

#### render()

```
recursiveRender = (component, idx = 0) => {
    const { data, children } = component;
    const { list } = this.props; 
    return (
        <div key={idx}>
            {
                children.map((child, childIdx) =>
                    this.recursiveRender(list[child], childIdx))
            }
        </div>
    );
};

render() {
    const { list } = this.props;
    return this.recursiveRender(list.root);
}
```

#### Redux Reducer

I want to update the order of the children of, let's say, `item_1`.

I do the following in my redux action:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
...
...
return update(state,
    {
        list: {
            [parent]: {
                children: {
                    $splice: [[oldIdx, 1], [idx, 0, id]] },
                },
        },
    }
});
```

which does work.

### Problem

I notice in React Dev Tools that *every one* (`item_2` and `item_3` too) of the recursively rendered component is repainted. I have no idea why. I'm making sure the `list` is immutable but the whole tree is rendered again every time. How can I make sure only the changed part (`item_1` here) of the `list` is repainted?

I don't think using `reselect` is the solution here since the list *is* changing indeed.

So, should I have a dynamic `mapStateToProps`? If so, how to not change other list items that depend on the `list`? Or am I looking at the wrong place and the problem can be elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Stateless functional components do not do any comparison between previous and new props. A simple solution would be to use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) for your `RecursiveRender` instead.

Comment: Oh, that did not work. Because I have other props in the component. But thank you!

Comment: Oh now that I'm checking again, I notice that you are providing the whole list object to the RecursiveRender which might be part of the issue. You could possibly write a function that would transform your list object so that instead of having the children as reference they would be replaced by the full object and then providing them recursive list.

Comment: I see. Yes! I'd give it a try. But I'm worried the 'transform' function is going to depend on the list somehow and react would repaint anyway. I'm trying to figure out exactly that.

Comment: Well if each on of the children is an immutable object I think that would solve the issue.

Comment: children is an array of strings - immutable. I'm using `immutability-helper` to make sure each of the object is also never mutated.